# Related Entries

Tags: relations, relatedto

I want to glue entries together across multiple sections.  My first thought is to use fields that are entry related, like blog would have the fields news, tutorials.  The tutorials section would contain the fields news and blogs.  **Is that the best way to glue the related entries together?**

Also I have looked and start messing with the **Reverse Relations Plugin** but I thought of something else.

**Would it be more efficient if I used Tags instead?** Just not sure what the best method is.  Has anyone come up with a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using Categories.

Entries Fields(relations) are great, but sometimes not the best organizing solution depending on the project. As you can see from your original post, you're already asking the question "Do I relate this to that or that to this?".

I'd stay away from tags as they are hard to manage, prone to error, and always end up a bit of a mess.

Comment: I am trying out categories now, good idea :).  I worked out what baseline data point would make sense for my site to glue it all together per entry.  What I find is that I could have hundreds of unique data points as categories.  Do I have that right, I imagine each one would need to be it's on category?

Also have you ever used the plugin **Reverse Relations**?  I am testing it out now.

Comment: I tried to get Categories working but since I am dealing with Solpace Calendar it's not a Section.  My setup is dealing with events, I am trying to get the Event to come up under the artists profile without having to add it in every time to their entry in the CP.  I have them listed on the event page but want to have that even show up on the artists page without having to do anything else.  Any ideas how I can accomplish that, I am out of ideas.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have experience with either Reverse Relations or Solspace Calendar. If you need it to be a section, Categories pretty much act like Structure channels. So create a structure channel but treat it like a category.

Comment: That is the thing, I don't want to be tied to Sections.  I have 5 Sections and I want them all to be able to relate to each other so categories don't really seem to work for that.  I added a entries field and for now choose the entries I want related.  Not great but it works.