# Reverse related entry with Solspace Calendar

Tags: relations, plugin-solspacecalendar

I'm using Solspace Calendar,
When I create an event with it I use a related entry field called 'project'
to choose an entry from a section called projects
I can display the project title etc in the Calendar template,
however I want to display the projects event date when on the project page (reverse related)
I can't fathom how to construct a reverse related entry – being 'events' is neither an entry, user, asset etc as per this question: [Related Entries](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/20267/related-entries)
I would like to understand if its even possible as for example - the plugin not being a section, this clearly won't work:

```
{% set relatedDates = craft.entries.section('events').relatedTo(entry) %}
```

how would one grab the calendar event to begin with?
Thanks

Comment: so basically the opposite of this (below) in that I have an entry field 'project'  
to use in the Calendar and can choose the project entry when I create an event, not choosing an event from a project like below:  
https://docs.solspace.com/craft/calendar/v2/overview/fieldtype.html#use-in-templates

Answer (score 2):

after reading and re-reading the docs got this working:

```
{% set relatedDates = craft.calendar.events.relatedTo(entry).all() %}

{% for relatedEventEntry in relatedDates %}
 {{ relatedEventEntry.title }} - {{ relatedEventEntry.startDate.format("l, F j, Y \\a\\t g:ia") }}
      ({{ relatedEventEntry.duration.humanReadable }})
      in {{ relatedEventEntry.calendar.name }} calendar.
      {% if relatedEventEntry.repeating %}
        Repeats {{ relatedEventEntry.readableRepeatRule }}
      {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

this is called from the `projects/_entry` template